# Url of item created in a document library using workflow

Tags: workflow

We have a list where if the user creates a new item the end product is a folder in a document library. We would like to have a column in the list that stores the url of the folder created in  the library.

We have worked out how to hard code this in but is there a way using workflow where we can dynamically get the **full** url of this item - doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint?

Comment: I don't think you can get the full folder URL from within a workflow on your list. I do think you could write the ID of the list item as a property of your folder, and from a workflow on the library when the folder is created, set a URL in the list item.

Answer (score 2):

Create a column in your library and set its value in workflow like following.

[image]

I have tested it by setting document's `URL` in `Title` column.

**Encoded Absolute URL** column will return you document's full `URL`.